# What is the reheating temperature of neutrinos during the BBN?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, nucleosynthesis

I want to integrate a differential distribution function of sterile neutrinos and the boundaries are the decoupling and the reheating temperature of neutrinos, but **I don't know what is an acceptable value for a reheating temperature**.

In most sources the neutrino's $T_{\text{decoupling}}$  $\approx 1 \text{MeV}$ ([p14 section B](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524) ; [p24 section 3.3.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07938)  and $1.5 \text{MeV}$ in [p1 Introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06655)).

But I keep on finding different values for the reheating temperature:

- Low reheating temperature:  $T_{RH} =5 \text{MeV and } T_{RH} =10 \text{MeV} ;  $ [p52 Figure 11](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07938)
- Low reheating temperature:  $T_{RH} =5 \text{MeV} $ ;  [p17 section 5.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01837)
- Reheating temperature boundaries: $T_R \lt 10^{6-7} \text{GeV}$ [p36 section 5.5](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0502169#:%7E:text=We%20explore%20in%20some%20detail,for%20the%20origin%20of%20matter.)

**What are the reasons behind choosing the correct temperature? How do I know which temperature is the correct reheating temperature?**

The idea I had from conversations with professors was that it had to be around $T_R = 10^{10} \text{GeV}$, but I don't understand why, as this was simply stated to me.

**Based on the following articles:**

- [Sterile Neutrinos as Dark Matter (1993)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287)
- [Sterile Neutrino Hot, Warm, and Cold Dark Matter (2001)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524)

Comment: The first two numbers you refer to are for *active* neutrinos, not sterile neutrinos. Most of the other numbers are bounds  on (not necessarily values for) the possible (currently unknown) reheating temperature for sterile neutrinos.

Comment: So when I try to put integration boundaries where T is my variable, like $\int^T_{reheating}_T_{decoupling}$, the top boundary, can be any number I find appropriate from the many papers being published.